# How to pause game for a certain time and resume again

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to pause my game for 2 seconds and continue again. I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
var duration = NSTimeInterval(2)
var wait=SKAction.waitForDuration(duration)
self.runAction(wait)
```

self is SKScene. Is there a different method to achieve this?

Comment: set the paused property of the node to YES whose child nodes you want to pause, for instance the "game layer" node. run an action sequence on the scene that waits and in the completion block set paused back to no

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `SKNode.isPaused` property. This is a Boolean value that determines whether actions on the node and its descendants are processed.

This means that if you set `self.paused = true` in the SKScene, all of the child nodes of the `scene` will be paused. You can also do it to individual nodes like sprites.

For more information
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html